# CONTROL DE INGRESO Y SALIDA EN PHP Y JS

Tags: javascript, php, json

saludos a todos estoy tratando de crear un formulario de control de entrada y salida basico, donde a traves de un lector de codigo de barras identifique a la persona, inicialmente contiene dos paginas, index.php y el formulario_registro. php, he querido hacer alguna validacion por Js pero no me ha funcionado, he consultado mucho pero no he podido pasar de ahi, soy nuevo y quiero desarrollar este control de entrada para la empresa pero es mas un reto familiarizarme con el codigo, pero al ver que lo he intentado demasiadas veces y no he tenido exito he requerido buscar ayuda de ustedes

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Registro de Empleados</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/formulario.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Registro de Empleados</h1>

    <form action="verificar_empleado.php"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="registroForm" onsubmit="return verificarRegistro()">
      <label for="codigo">Código:</label>
      <input type="text" id="codigo" class="codigo-de-barras" name="codigo" required style="font-family: 'Code128', sans-serif;" autocomplete= off>
      <label for="nombre">Nombre Completo:</label>
      <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required autocomplete= off>
      <label for="cedula">Número de Cédula:</label>
      <input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula" required autocomplete= off>
      <label for="cargo">Cargo:</label>
      <input type="text" id="cargo" name="cargo" required autocomplete= off>
      <label for="foto">Fotografía:</label>
      <input type="file" id="foto" name="foto" accept="image/*" required>
      <button type="submit" onclick="setAction('verificar_empleado.php')">Guardar</button><br><hr>
      <a href="../index.php">Inicio</a>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="aviso" class="aviso oculto">
    <span id="aviso-mensaje"></span>
    <button id="cerrar-aviso" onclick="cerrarAviso()">Cerrar</button>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
    function verificarRegistro() {
    const codigo = document.getElementById('codigo').value;

    // Realizar la petición AJAX
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            console.log('Respuesta del servidor recibida'); // Para verificar si la respuesta del servidor fue recibida
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // Verificar qué hay en la respuesta del servidor

            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(response); // Verificar la estructura de la respuesta del servidor

                if (response.existe) {
                    mostrarAviso("El empleado ya está registrado.");
                    console.log(response)
                    return false; // Evita que el formulario se envíe
                } else {
                    console.log('Empleado no registrado, se enviará el formulario.');
                    return true; // Permite que el formulario se envíe
                }
            } else {
                alert('Error en la solicitud');
                return false; // Evita que el formulario se envíe en caso de error
                console.log(response)
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open('POST', '../php/verificar_empleado.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('codigo=' + codigo);

    return false; // Para prevenir el envío predeterminado del formulario
}

    <?php
```

```
include 'conexion.php'; // Incluye el archivo de conexión

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['codigo'])) {
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];

    // Consulta preparada para verificar si el empleado ya está registrado
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE codigo = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $codigo);

    // Ejecuta la consulta
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $resultado = $stmt->get_result();

        if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
            echo json_encode(array('existe' => true));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('existe' => false));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('existe' => false));
    }

    // Cierra la declaración y resultados
    $stmt->close();
    $resultado->close();
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('existe' => false));
}

// Cierra la conexión
$conn->close();
?>
```

```
    <?php
include 'conexion.php'; // Incluye el archivo de conexión

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Obtener datos del formulario
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo']; // Asegúrate de obtener el código del formulario
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
    $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];

    // Consulta preparada para insertar datos de manera segura
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO empleados (codigo, nombre, cedula, cargo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    
    // Vincular parámetros
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $codigo, $nombre, $cedula, $cargo);

    // Ejecutar la consulta
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Empleado registrado correctamente";
    } else {
        echo "Error al registrar el empleado: " . $stmt->error;
    }
    
    // Cerrar la declaración
    $stmt->close();
}

// Cerrar la conexión al finalizar las operaciones
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: El idioma del sitio es el Español, por favor traduce tu pregunta. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasa que estas retornando siempre `false` en tu función `verificarRegistro`.

Todos los `return` que están dentro de `xhr.onreadystatechange` **NO** son el retorno de la función `verificarRegistro`, son solo el retorno del evento `onreadystatechange` y como este evento funciona como `callback` tampoco tienes manera de capturar dicho retorno.

La solución es crear una variable:

```
   function verificarRegistro() {

    let retorno = false; //COLOCAMOS ESTO!

    const codigo = document.getElementById('codigo').value;

    // Realizar la petición AJAX
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            console.log('Respuesta del servidor recibida'); // Para verificar si la respuesta del servidor fue recibida
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // Verificar qué hay en la respuesta del servidor

            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(response); // Verificar la estructura de la respuesta del servidor

                if (response.existe) {
                    mostrarAviso("El empleado ya está registrado.");
                    console.log(response)
                    retorno = false; // Seteamos retorno
                } else {
                    console.log('Empleado no registrado, se enviará el formulario.');
                    retorno = true; // Seteamos retorno
                }
            } else {
                alert('Error en la solicitud');
                retorno = false; // Seteamos retorno
                console.log(response)
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open('POST', '../php/verificar_empleado.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('codigo=' + codigo);

    return retorno; // Para prevenir el envío predeterminado del formulario
}
```

---

Por otro lado yo te recomiendo cambiar varias cosas, principalmente

- XMLHttpRequest por [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/fetch)
- En el servidor devolver [códigos HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status), así por ejemplo si el código es no valido devuelves un código 400 en vez de un json con un array que tiene un false. Para esto en PHP usas [http_response_code](https://www.php.net/http-response-code)

Comment: excelente, muchas gracias por tu ayuda